# android transparent circle inside layout on mapview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an application in which i have to show a map with the aim on it. just like it is on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gLbD.png). When a user drags map with a finger, map is moving and the aim isn't. I can make a translucent layout over the map, but can't understand how to draw a transparent circle. Please give me some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends how you're drawing the translucent overlay, but if you were using Canvas methods, you can try with the clip methods to intersect with a path. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was decided to use the 9-patch for different screen density.This way proved to be easier for this case.